# Jmeter WebDriver Sampler run in browser without incognito mode

Tags: jmeter, webdriver

I have webdriver script for WEB UI testing but Response time getting from WebDriver Sampler is more than real browser by manually.
I ran the script in headless mode and still getting high response time.

I want to ask if there is any way to Open chrome in normal window without incognito mode, Because incognito mode already load fresh page along with css/images/styles, it does not use cached loaded images/css/styles.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the current version of the [WebDriver Sampler 3.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/kg.apc/jmeter-plugins-webdriver/3.1) manipulating browser profile is not possible unless you want to patch the code of the relevant [Config Element](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins-webdriver/tree/master/src/main/java/com/googlecode/jmeter/plugins/webdriver/config) yourself.

You can consider switching from the WebDriver Sampler to the [JSR223 Sampler and Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) language where you will have the full freedom when it comes to the browser instantiation, for example you will be able to:

- [Start Firefox with the given profile](https://www.guru99.com/firefox-profile-selenium-webdriver.html)
- [Specify user-data-dir for Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51680314/2897748)

However my expectation is that you should be starting "clean" session for each user, just add more iterations in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group), first opening of your application will be slow, but on subsequent requests the heavy content like images, scripts, styles, fonts, sounds, etc. will be returned from browser cache and will be fast.